# Mongodb - Finding GeoNear within nested JSON objects

Tags: json, mongodb, geolocation, mongodb-query

I need to get the closest place near a certain point using this data structure:

```
    [
    {
        "data_id": "127",
        "actual_data": [
            {
                "id": "220",
                "value": "shaul"
            },
            {
                "id": "221",
                "value": "3234324"
            },
            {
                "id": "222",
                "value": {
                    "lngalt": [
                        13.7572225,
                        -124.0429047
                    ],
                    "street_number": null,
                    "political": null,
                    "country": null,
                }
            },
            {
                "id": "223",
                "value": "dqqqf1222fs3d7ddd77@Dcc11cS2112s.com"
            },
            {
                "id": "224",
                "value": "123123"
            },
            {
                "id": "225",
                "value": "lala1"
            },
....
    },
    {
        "data_id": "133",
        "actual_data": [
            {
                "id": "260",
                "value": {
                    "lngalt": [
                        1.7572225,
                        32.0429047
                    ],
                    "street_number": null,
                    "political": null,
                    "country": null,
                }
            },
            {
                "id": "261",
                "value": -122.25
            }
        ],
    }
]
```

I used the following query in order to get what I need:

```
{
    "actual_data": {
        "$elemMatch": {
            "id": "260",
            "value.lngalt": {
                "$near": {
                    "$geometry": {
                        "type": "Point",
                        "coordinates": [
                            -73.9667,
                            40.78
                        ]
                    },
                    "$minDistance": 1000,
                    "$maxDistance": 5000
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But after queering it, I get "Can't canonicalize query: BadValue geoNear must be top-level expr" (error code: 17287). It's strange since I do get the right results when I query without the $near but with $elemMatch only in order to get the exact object with particular value.

Thanks.

**SOLVED!**

for future refarance I used $geoWithin instead $near function. So my query looks like :

```
{
    "actual_data": {
        "$elemMatch": {
            "id": "260",
            "value.lnglat": {
                "$geoWithin": {
                    "$centerSphere": [
                        [
                            -71.07651880000003,
                            42.353068
                        ],
                        0.001
                     ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

PEACE!

Comment: `$elemMatch` doesn't supported `$near` nested inside. Note also that the matches will be for documents, not elements of the array, so I don't think that, even if your query worked, it would give you what you expect. Are you trying to find the nearest point among the points in the document? Or the document which has, among its various points, the nearest (as compared to the other documents)?

Comment: I try to fine an whole document(s) that contains a sub object with ID equals to 260 and near the specific coordinates. so if the ID is not 260 it will not get returned.